# Any alternative to 'Facebook Activity Feed' plugin, as its getting deprecated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the title states, I am looking for any quick and easy alternative to implement something like 'Facebook Activity Feed' plugin.

The one that Facebook had is now being deprecated on 23rd June 2015.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/activity

I am sure either Facebook will be providing some quick alternative or there must be some plugin already out there that does something similar. Don't want to spend lots of time creating my own using the new Graph API.

Comment: I'm not aware of any direct alternatives, but you can use Like Button plugin to share likes (and include Friends' faces).

Answer (score 2):

No idea why they're not linking to it, from their activity feed, but the Page Plugin is pretty much the Activity Feed, just with a fresh look.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The activity feed worked on a single domain, whereas the page plugin is directly related to a particular page on Facebook. The activity feed showed activity on a particular website, whereas the page plugin shows what's happening on a particular page (which might be related to a particular website) on Facebook.

Comment: If anybody has trouble with making feed for business.facebook.com/UrPage, Simply replace 'business' with www.